# C#: Only top-level controls can have an owner. (Metro framework)

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child, parent

I get this `Only top-level controls can have an owner.` exception even if I already set my child form's toplevel to false.

Here's my code for my main form:

```
    public Form childform;
    public void innerChild(Form child)
            {
                breaker();
                childform = child;
                childform.TopLevel = false;
                splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(childform);
                childform.Show(); //**Toplevel e**
            }

    private void breaker()
            {
                try
                {
                    childform.Close();
                    childform.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }
            }

     private void btnSupProd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                innerChild(new Supplier_Supplies(this));
}
```

Here's the related code in my child form:

```
MySqlConnection conn;
public Dashboard reftomain;
public Supplier_Supplies(Dashboard main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            reftomain = main;
            this.TopLevel = false;
            conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=sample; uid=root; pwd=");
        }
```

I'm trying to get the child form to show in my main form's panel. But this error keeps on persisting, help?

Stack Trace:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Only top-level controls can have an owner.
Parameter name: value
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Owner(Form value)
   at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.MetroShadowBase..ctor(Form targetForm, Int32 shadowSize, Int32 wsExStyle)
   at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.MetroFlatDropShadow..ctor(Form targetForm)
   at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.CreateShadow()
   at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
   at Jacam_Merchat.Dashboard.innerChild(Form child) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAD 2\Jacam Merchat\Jacam Merchat\Dashboard.cs:line 37
   at Jacam_Merchat.Dashboard.btnSupProd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAD 2\Jacam Merchat\Jacam Merchat\Dashboard.cs:line 64
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTile.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Jacam_Merchat.Program.Main() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAD 2\Jacam Merchat\Jacam Merchat\Program.cs:line 19
```

Comment: Hard to guess with this library, a stack trace would be nice.  Changing the "child" type from MetroForm to MetroUserControl would be the most obvious wise thing to do.

Comment: Added stack trace, I'm not sure what to do now at this point

Comment: Shoot, I actually guessed at this. MetroForm has too much code that assumes that it is being used as a toplevel window instead of a child control.  Such a window has a dropshadow, but MetroForm is borderless so it has to emulate one.  That can't work when it is child control.  It would be easy to fix in the code, just check if the TopLevel property is false and bypass the call to CreateShadow() .  But there can be other failure modes, you should do this the right way and change the base class to MetroUserControl.

Comment: Hey its been a while, apologies for only replying now.

TopLevel property is false and as of right now I'm having trouble creating a shadow for it. Also I don't know what I'm doing wrong but "MetroUserControl" isn't being recognized as a base class.

Answer (score 7):

Tested it out.

Set shadowtype to none on the child form

Hope this helps.
Happy Coding.